# Stitching images together by finding similarities in the images?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am writing an app that stitches iOS text message screen captures together vertically.
I have the images cropped to only contain the message bubbles and none of the navigation bar of the text input bar (expect the the first and last screencaps of course) but I don't know how to detect where to line up the images.
I need to detect where there is overlap in the conversations and then stitch the images at the point.  (I know how to draw the images to a new image context too.)
I am looking for an open source framework that could help me achieve this and any advice as to how to accomplish this task.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can also give a go to the following code:

https://github.com/foundry/OpenCVStitch

Answer (score 1):

While it might be overkill for your project, you could have a look at [PanoTools](http://panotools.sourceforge.net/): an Open Source software library for manipulating and stitching panoramic images. It's portable (Win/Lin/Mac), and if you're looking forward to making the stitching on your computer, GUIs to it like [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/) may even already fit your use case (I only used them for stitching photographs, so check the projection settings).